# React native floating button

Tags: react-native, floating-action-button

I've created bottom navigation with a custom floating button inside. Button/Menu is opening, but elements inside (with a red circle) are not touchable because the gray container is above them probably. This small fragment of the blue add button which is overlapping the gray container is also not touchable.
I was trying to add zIndex/elevation for menu buttons - but it doesn't help.
How to make a whole floating menu above on all containers.
All elements have a position set to absolute.

**Code Reference**
https://gist.github.com/gtarnowski/3b36deaeed71abee3d5e84567aa37eea
**Image Reference**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGkw0.jpg

Comment: Can you paste your code, please?

Comment: @LineuPastorelli Sure, Added

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the code you sent me and it seems to be working correctly. It's emitting the logs.

Below is the Snack link I created:

https://snack.expo.dev/@lineuxyz/greg-error

Comment: Generally, it's working well. But if you try to use it as a part of BottomTopBar - it doesn't work. Try to wrap it by  `<Tab.Screen/>`

Comment: But this code that you passed, is it the same one you are using?